# How to remove multiple event delegates using single undelegate method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I make the following much simpler (instead of using 'undelegate' twice)?

```
$("#div1").undelegate("div", "mouseenter").undelegate("div", "mouseleave");
```

I don't want event handlers other than mouseenter and mouseleave to get disturbed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Split your events with spaces.

```
$("#div1").undelegate("div", "mouseenter mouseleave");
```

You should use `on` and `off` though.

```
$("#div1").off("mouseenter mouseleave", "div");
```

http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/

> The .undelegate() method is a way of removing event handlers that have
>   been bound using .delegate(). As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off()
>   methods are preferred for attaching and removing event handlers.

Comment: the documentation says it can take a map of events, does this space delimited list really work?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, you can use the shorthand [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```
​$("#div1").off("hover", "div");
```

​
[`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is the recommended way for removing event handlers as of jQuery 1.7.